# How to get Images from cloudant DB and show those images through UI

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

Images are stored in cloudant DB in JSON Format.I need to get those images from cloudant and show it through UI. Please share the docs related to this it will be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Unfortunately, your question does not meet the stackoverflow criteria for good questions and will likely get closed.  See here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

information for storing and retrieving images (i.e., attachments) from Cloudant are here:

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/attachments.html#attachments

or if you are using the cloudant-nano/nodejs-cloudant library:

https://github.com/cloudant-labs/cloudant-nano#attachments-functions

once you retrieve the image, there are multiple ways to display it (depending on your environment):

- [display image attach from couchDB in html via flask/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40812940/display-image-attach-from-couchdb-in-html-via-flask-python)
- [Serving file with CouchDB attachment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902609/serving-file-with-couchdb-attachment)
- [How can I display an image out of a document's attachments in CouchDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038323/how-can-i-display-an-image-out-of-a-documents-attachments-in-couchdb)